# nothing visible in tkinter

Tags: function, tkinter, button

When i start the Application, the Buttons are not visible. Im new with Python and tkinter. I appreciate, if somebody can explain me, what i do wrong.
I placed the Buttons with `.place` in `self.frame`.

Thank you in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class WindowMain:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        master.configure(menu=self)
        
        menuleiste = Menu(self.frame)
        datei_menu = Menu(menuleiste, tearoff=0)

        datei_menu.add_command(label="Einlesen", command=lambda:[button_ust()])
                
        menuleiste.add_cascade(label="Datei", menu=datei_menu)
        
        button_ust = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Umsatz/Steuer\n Auswertung', command=lambda:[button_ust()], bg='#393939', fg='white')
        button_ust.place(x = 60, y = 40, width=200, height=75)
        bestand_button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Lagerbestand\n auswerten', command=lambda:[button_bestand()], bg='#393939', fg='white')
        bestand_button.place(x = 290, y = 40, width=200, height=75)
        
        self.frame.pack()
        
    def button_ust(self):
        self.button_ust = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = WindowUSt(self.button_ust)
        
class WindowUSt:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.geometry('400x100')
        self.resizable(False,False)
        fileButton = Button(self, text='Datei suchen',)
        fileButton.pack(expand=True)
        fileButton.place(x=280, y=22, height=40, width=100)
        
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = WindowMain(root)
    root.geometry('550x280')
    root.resizable(False,False)
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you using `master.configure(menu=self)`, if you aren't inheriting from a `tkinter` widget/window?

Comment: first i tryed to use `self.config(menu=menuleiste)`, because that doesn't worked i tried this.

Comment: You have never called any layout function, `.pack()` / `grid()` / `place()`, on `self.frame` inside `WindowMain.__init__()`.  Even though you fix the above issue, there are still other issues in your code.

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve]. Start removing code, and keep removing code as long as the problem persists. If the problem is with the visibility of buttons, we likely don't need most of the functions. As a quick guess, I would say it's because your code isn't adding `MainWindow` to the root with `pack`, `place`, or `grid`.

Comment: The Problem was, that i placed ```self.frame.pack()```, i solved now. Now its placed with ```self.frame.place(x=0,y=0, width=550, height=280)``` With full height and width.